# Passing a property of type A into a method (5 possible properties as input) - differentiating input

Tags: objective-c, properties, polymorphism

I have 5 `RotorView` objects (subclass of `UIView`) that each need to be animated/transformed at different duration periods.  Each is a private property in my `MotorViewController` class.

Instead of writing 5 different rotation methods to handle each object (which would go against the point of polymorphism), I want to be able to pass in the right property to `firstRotation`, and transform it appropriately.

The code below uses `self.rotorLarge` (which is my current `RotorView` property).  However, I will now want to use that method on `RotorView` properties `self.sample`, `self.air`, `self.waste`, and `self.lowLoss`.

Ignore the fact that each `RotorView` will also have it's own properties to handle speed (`double`), angle of rotation (`CGFloat`), and on/off (`bool`).

```
- (void)firstRotation
{
    [UIView animateWithDuration:self.motorSpeedAnimate
                          delay:0.0
                        options:UIViewAnimationOptionCurveLinear
                     animations:^{
                         self.rotorLarge.transform = CGAffineTransformRotate(self.rotorLarge.transform, self.angle);
                     }
                     completion:^(BOOL finished) {
                         if (self.rotorOn) {
                             NSLog(@"Done.");
                         }
                     }];
}
```

How do I go about doing this where an arbitrary `RotorView` property input can affect a specific private `RotorView` property after transformation?

Thanks for the help.

I am using iOS 11.3 and Obj-C language.

Answer (score 0):

Try below code

```
       - (void)firstRotation:(RotorView *)instanceView {
 [UIView animateWithDuration:self.motorSpeedAnimate
                      delay:0.0
                    options:UIViewAnimationOptionCurveLinear
                 animations:^{
                     instanceView.transform = CGAffineTransformRotate(instanceView.transform, instanceView.angle);
                 }
                 completion:^(BOOL finished) {
                     if (instanceView.rotorOn) {
                         NSLog(@"Done.");
                     }
                 }];}
```

For calling

```
[self firstRotation:self.sample];
```